# Create an input link in javaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, input, click, zooming

I can zoom my browser
In the http://jsfiddle.net/gHdPT/4/
I would replace the A + by the input Zoom in and Zoom out

```
window.ZoomScreen = function (amount) {
    document.body.style.webkitTransform =
    document.body.style.msTransform =
    document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + amount + ')';
    document.body.style.width = 100 / amount + '%';
}

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, qui, sunt, totam quaerat repudiandae dignissimos maxime et perspiciatis aperiam doloremque eaque eum explicabo ullam deleniti sed adipisci obcaecati fuga similique.</p>
        <a href="#" onclick="ZoomScreen(1)">A+</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="ZoomScreen(1.5)">A+</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="ZoomScreen(2)">A+</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="ZoomScreen(2.5)">A+</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

How? thank you

Comment: sorry I forgot the code http://jsfiddle.net/gHdPT/4/

Comment: Still don't see the code here...

Comment: Sorry but I can not put it in my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't clearly understood you.

Is this what you need?
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/coshmos/VGMP2/

Html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, qui, sunt, totam quaerat repudiandae dignissimos maxime et perspiciatis aperiam doloremque eaque eum explicabo ullam deleniti sed adipisci obcaecati fuga similique.</p>
<a href="#" onclick="ZoomIn()">A+</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ZoomOut()">A-</a>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var zoomLevel = 1;

window.ZoomIn = function () {
    zoomLevel += 0.5;
    document.body.style.webkitTransform =
        document.body.style.msTransform =
        document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')';
    document.body.style.width = 100 / zoomLevel + '%';
}

window.ZoomOut = function () {
    zoomLevel -= 0.5;
    document.body.style.webkitTransform =
        document.body.style.msTransform =
        document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')';
    document.body.style.width = 100 / zoomLevel + '%';
}
```

CSS:

```
body {margin: 0 auto;-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0; transform-origin: 50% 0;}
.container{background: #000;}
p{color:#fff;}
a { color: #FFCC00;}
```

Comment: How to validate your answer? sorry for my bad English? sorry for my bad English?

Comment: Look at the top left corner of my answer. You'll see a check mark: http://i.imgur.com/pBR52PN.png Just click on it. Thanks.